# Launch program web clients

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer, cmd

I'm working on an intranet for a society.
I created some programs.
What i need is when a client is clicking on a `<button>` of my web site, the program is launched.
Some of my programs are .jar in clients's computers.
I will need to launch them with arguments.
I know it's impossible to launch cmd command with a website on the client's desktop. But is it possible to launch programs ? My clients are on IE.

I tryed this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var obj = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell" );
  obj.run('explorer.exe /e "C:\\ton dossier"', 0, true);
</script>
```

But it just open me the document folder (always).
Any idea ?

Comment: are you sure that "ton dossier" is an application, a document or ist just the partent folder? Usually explorer should start the associated program on i.e. `obj.run('explorer.exe /e "C:\\ton dossier.docx"', 0, true);` (mind the suffix!)

Comment: obj.run('C:\Java\jre\bin\java.exe "C:\\Users\adm_adv\Desktop\ouvrir.jar"', 0, true); returned me "Error", my .jar works when i double click on it.

Comment: In order to start up jar files fromout the browser, you could use java web start, just google for that

Comment: I tried to, but there is a problem, it's working but my java codes are very small, and when i'm launching them with "java web start" it takes a lot of time to open it (this button to open the ;jar will be use a lot of time per day, dont want to wait :/) When i execute the .jar file, its very quick :)

Answer (score 0):

I found it :

```
WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.Run("c:/Users/adm_adv/Desktop/ouvrir.jar C:", 1, false);
```

Thx all.

Comment: PS : The last "C:" in the command is a parameter for my jar program.